# Why is Eclipse ignoring run configuration environment variables?

Tags: java, eclipse, osx-lion, environment-variables, java-6

Mac OSX Lion 10.7.4.  Eclipse "Juno Release 20120614-1722".

OK, been bashing my head against this for hours.  I have a Java console application that uses JNI libraries.  It runs great from the command line, once I satisfied the JNI library's dependencies on environment variables I set.  But I cannot get any Run configuration to run the application from Eclipse with the same environment variables that I have in my shell.

I have added these variables repeatedly to different kinds of run configurations.

I added a prefatory method to emit the needed environment variables and they keep on coming up not unset, but empty.  Huh???!?

I deleted all my Eclipse prefs files and caches and such and it still won't work.

I got it working at one point but never again.

There must be something screwy with Eclipse on Mac or maybe the Juno version that is killing me.  Anyone have any ideas or suggestions?

Thanks,

Andrew Wolfe

Comment: Are your JNI libraries loading correctly?  If you look in the `Debug view>Properties` on your process, does the command line eclipse used to launch it look reasonable (with the native property defined)?

Comment: From within the program code, I am System.out.println'ing out env (DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH) and the key home variable, they're coming out blank.
I'm running the process straight, not in the debugger.

There ought to be a way to see the entire command line.  I suppose I could put a pause in and examine the process with ps -fp <pid>....  I'd think Eclipse could already have something like that.  I'm not up on the multiverse of plugins.
I will try your suggestion and run in Debug and view the process properties.  Thanks @PaulWebster!

Comment: @PaulWebster Eclipse seems to arbitrarily filter values out of environment variables. The OP and I would like to know how to stop it from doing this. (My problem is directories being removed from `PATH`).

Comment: Sorry, my issue is unrelated and solved itself by rebooting Windows (somehow the environment was being cached by whatever launched eclipse when started via the Start menu…).